# Codable protocol error "The given data was not valid JSON."

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting an error having to do with the codable protocol

```
struct UsersResponse : Codable {
    let directoryItems: [DirectoryItem]
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case directoryItems = "directory_items"
    }
}

struct DirectoryItem : Codable {
    let user : User
}

struct User : Codable {
    let id: Int
    let userName: String
    let imageURL: String
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case userName = "username"
        case imageURL = "avatar_template"
    }
}
```

This is my JSON response on Postman, the keys are well defined in the protocol, honestly I don't really know what is going wrong. 
Here is the full error object. 
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})))

```
{
"directory_items": [
{
"id": 0,
"likes_received": 0,
"likes_given": 0,
"topics_entered": 0,
"topic_count": 0,
"post_count": 0,
"posts_read": 0,
"days_visited": 0,
"user": {
"id": 0,
"username": "string",
"avatar_template": "string",
"name": "string",
"title": { }
}
}
],
"total_rows_directory_items": 0,
"load_more_directory_items": "string"
}
```

This is where I ask for the data

```
func send<T: APIRequest>(request: T, completion: @escaping(Result<T.Response, Error>) -> ()) {
        let request = request.requestWithBaseUrl()
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            do {
                guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { return }
                if response.statusCode >= 400 && response.statusCode < 500 {
                    if let data = data {
                        let errorModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(DiscourseAPIError.self, from: data)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let errorString = errorModel.errors?.joined(separator: ", ") ?? "Unknown error"
                            completion(.failure(NSError(domain: "request error", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: errorString])))
                        }
                    } else {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            completion(.failure(SessionAPIError.emptyData))
                        }
                    }
                }
                if let data = data {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                    print(json)
                    let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.Response.self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(.success(model))
                    }
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(.failure(SessionAPIError.emptyData))
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print(error)
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Show more code. You ask for the data how? The data comes in how? Then what?

Comment: So T.Response is UsersResponse? Can you prove that?

Comment: Yes, when I pass the closure it has UsersResponse set as the parameter

Comment: It is saying that there is invalid JSON around character 0 - So, there may be some invalid, unprintable data at the start.  What if you convert your data to a UTF 8 string a print it?  What if you convert it to an array of bytes and dump it?

Comment: @Paulw11 I thought that too but then how do you explain that JsonSerialization prints it out happily?

Comment: Here is the thing guys JsonSerialization does not print the data! I tried setting the allowFragments option which is why it was complaining and still it didn't print it!

Comment: When I try printing a the JSON it does not print anything @Paulw11

Comment: Here is the thing guys JsonSerialization does not print the data! I tried setting the allowFragments option which is why it was complaining and still it didn't print it! @matt

Comment: @Paulw11 When I print the data it gives me an HTML document

Comment: You may need to set a header to specify you want `application/json` - What does the HTML document say?  It will probably tell you what the problem is.

Comment: @Paulw11 That's exactly what I did still it did not work

Comment: What does the server response say? Have you tested the endpoint with Postman or similar?

Comment: “When I print the data it gives me an HTML document” ... Yep, this is very common if there was some problem with the request. So, I’d suggest saving the `data` to a file (w `html` extension), copy it over to your Mac, and then opening it up in a browser so you can figure out what that document is saying. Often buried in the HTML is some information about what went wrong. Maybe the authorization failed? Maybe the request was subtly malformed. We can’t tell on the basis that’s been shared with us so far. But open the HTML up in a browser and you might just have some interesting info there.

Comment: Another useful technique is to use a diagnostic tool like [Charles](https://charlesproxy.com) or [WireShark](https://wireshark.org). It will take a little work to configure it, but they’re extremely useful tools once you do have them configured properly, because you can run the app on a simulator, but actually examine the details of the request and the response right in that third party utility. Like I said, it takes a little work to get it up and running, but once you do, it will become an invaluable tool that you’re return to again and again in your programming career.

Answer (score -1):

In a playground, I copied your sample json and got this output:

```swift
let sample = """
{
"directory_items": [
{
"id": 0,
"likes_received": 0,
"likes_given": 0,
"topics_entered": 0,
"topic_count": 0,
"post_count": 0,
"posts_read": 0,
"days_visited": 0,
"user": {
"id": 0,
"username": "string",
"avatar_template": "string",
"name": "string",
"title": { }
}
}
],
"total_rows_directory_items": 0,
"load_more_directory_items": "string"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: sample, options: [])

print(json)
//{
//    "directory_items" =     (
//                {
//            "days_visited" = 0;
//            id = 0;
//            "likes_given" = 0;
//            "likes_received" = 0;
//            "post_count" = 0;
//            "posts_read" = 0;
//            "topic_count" = 0;
//            "topics_entered" = 0;
//            user =             {
//                "avatar_template" = string;
//                id = 0;
//                name = string;
//                title =                 {
//                };
//                username = string;
//            };
//        }
//    );
//    "load_more_directory_items" = string;
//    "total_rows_directory_items" = 0;
//}
```

The json is definitely valid. I'd be willing to bet that the suggested comment by [Paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11) is absolutely on point. There's probably a leading value that's breaking the rest of the JSON.

A potential simple way to clean it up would be to convert to a utf8 string and back to data, but that's more cpu cycles than necessary, especially if this is a frequently run code snippet.

There would be other, more efficient ways to clean it up, but this would at least let you confirm if this is a valid path forward or not.

(ps. please don't judge my force unwraps! it's just a playground and proof of concept!)